# avoid partition messages with unattended preseed file

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, preseed

I'm configuring an unattended installation with one NTFS partition (to be used later) and then root, swap and home partitions.

d-i keeps asking me about the first partition, and I want to avoid that confirmation message. this is the relevant part of my preseed file:

```
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
d-i partman-auto/method string regular
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string seperate-home :: 60000 10000p 60000 ntfs $primary{ } $bootable{ } method{ keep } . 20000 20000 20000 ext4 $primary{ } $bootable{ } method{ format } format{ } use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } mountpoint{ / } . 2000 3000 4000 linux-swap method{ swap } format{ } . 100 10000 1000000000 ext4 method{ format } format{ } use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } mountpoint{ /home } .
d-i partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
```

I've also tried formatting the partition:

```
60000 10000p 60000 ntfs $primary{ } $bootable{ } method{ format } format{ } use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ntfs } .
```

and I've been digging a while in forums without success.

Answer (score 1):

I can partially respond to my question.

partman supports only partially NTFS so certain operations can't be handled directly.

If I change ntfs to fat32 on my first recipe it works and no prompt is presented.

I still would like to know an option to avoid any pause, even in case of errors.